# When Windows says, "Unable to execute file in the temporary directory", where is this "temporary directory" located?

Tags: windows-7, temporary-files

"Unable to execute file in the temporary directory" pops up when I want to install files.

I want to know, when I open an installation executable, to which folder the files from that executable goes to? Which folder that pop-up is referring to?

Does it go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` or to `C:\temp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

As seen [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/where-is-the-temporary-folder/44a039a5-45ba-48dd-84db-fd700e54fd56) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1acff9e0-101a-4a0d-93e5-cd3230fbeefa/unable-to-execute-files-in-the-temporary-directory-setup-aborted-error-5-access-is-denied?forum=w7itprogeneral)

Comment: Yes I've seen that, but it's not clear enough if that is that is the said folder (the folder where temporary installation files goes to).

Comment: A non admin user has write access to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp but not C:\temp

Comment: So they don't have write access to C:\Temp? Meaning, if I change the file location from C:\Temp to D:\Temporary (for example), the non-admin user will have the write access?

Comment: @deathlock, AEonAX's post is more than clear. I have no idea why you don't understand it. You asked which directory, and you've had an answer. You are now asking a new question in a comment, please don't do this. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: A non admin user has _guranteed_ write access to %USERPROFILE%\ and anything within, Nothing cannot be said about other directories outside. depends upon the permissions given to the user.

Comment: @DaveRook: sorry if I wrote my question a bit unclear. I want to know, when I open an installation executable, to WHICH folder the files from that executable goes to? Does it go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` or to `C:\temp`? Or both? That's all I want to know. Let me revise my question.

Comment: @deathlock, your question is clear, and you've had it answered, with 2 sources to validate the answer! Not sure what else you want

Comment: @DaveRook: Okay, sorry. Didn't realize it was edited, or maybe I just didn't grasp the answer. I wonder then what is the use of `C:/Temp`? Or does this warrant a new question?

Comment: @deathlock It does, but, I will answer it here! I'm a software developer. I use the C:\Temp for temporary storage. For example, if I'm working with files (like creating a file), I may initially save it (them) to the temp folder. It is only when the file(s) is created (as the file could take a long time to create) will I then transfer it to the correct place. The reason is, most users don't use the temp folder and so are not tempted to try and open a file part created (which could happen if the file was visible by being created on the desktop)!

Comment: @deathlock some apps seem to use C:/Temp. Reading your Previous [question](http://superuser.com/questions/676621/unable-to-execute-file-in-the-temporary-directory-error-5-access-is-denied) I would suggest you try copying the erroring setup to both the temp directories and running them and see where the error occurs. it looks mostly to AntiVirus/Antispyware locking files issue

Comment: You can use `%localappdata%\Temp`, or even better just `%temp%`.

Answer (score 0):

it is %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp this directory.

check this answer [Unable to execute file in the temporary directory. Error 5. Access is denied](https://superuser.com/questions/676621/unable-to-execute-file-in-the-temporary-directory-error-5-access-is-denied)

Comment: I know that question - I'm the one who asked it. :) It's still unclear which folder is used to store files for temporary installation.

Comment: are you getting same error if you run it as administrator?